# PDA seeds: expected u8, found u32

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am trying to derive a pda using a u32 number. It seems that the seeds can only take u8 numbers. Is there a way to change this and use a u32 number as input for the seed?

[image]

edit: I am using Anchor.

Comment: does `user_id.uid.to_be_bytes()` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert u32 to u8 array with `to_be_bytes()`

Comment: Would you perhaps know what format to send the u32 number from the frontend? Can't get this in the same format when I use the to_be_bytes() in the Anchor program. 

Deriving the PDA in Anchor: 
`#[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8 + 32 + 1 + 32 + 1 + 10, seeds = [b"user_profile".as_ref(), &user_id.uid.to_be_bytes().as_ref() ], bump)]`

The seeds in the front-end:
`anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode('user_profile'),`
`new anchor.BN(user_id_pda.uid).toBuffer(),`

Where the `uid` is a u32 number (user_id.uid and user_id_pda.uid).

Comment: e.g. `new anchor.BN(18)` will send u32 to anchor program from the frontend