# How to convert number to buffer in Anchor TS test

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test

I have this seeds

`seeds = [b"game".as_ref(),authority.key().as_ref(),player_one_account.games_count.to_be_bytes().as_ref()]`

The games_count is a `u16`.

I want to create a PDA with these seeds :

```
            let gamesCount = fPlayer.gamesCount.toString();
            gamePDA] = await PublicKey
            .findProgramAddress(
                [
                    anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("game"),
                    user.publicKey.toBuffer(),
                    anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(gamesCount)
                ],
                program.programId
            );
```

But i am getting `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The seeds shoud be:

```
const [gamePDA] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [
    Buffer.from("game"),
    user.publicKey.toBuffer(),
    new anchor.BN(fPlayer.gameCount).toArrayLike(Buffer, "be", "2"),
  ],
  program.programId
);
```

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: Please refer to this PR.
https://github.com/raindrops-protocol/raindrops/pull/13

Comment: Thanks for the link but what does `For compatibility with browserify and similar tools` mean ?

Comment: Hope this answers your question.
https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser
https://browserify.org

Comment: Ok thanks, I will use that but please DO NOT DOWN VOTE my answer because It's ok to use not the best.

Comment: I didn't down the vote...

Answer (score 0):

After searching for while I found [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/pda-seeds-expected-u8-found-u32/1823#1823) the issue was `anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(gamesCount)` and the solution was to write that as `new anchor.BN(fPlayer.gamesCount).toBuffer("be",2)`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who the other solutions don't work for, you can try this:

```
Buffer.from(fPlayer.gamesCount.toString(16).padStart(8, '0'), 'hex')
```

In case you have `.to_le_bytes()` instead of `.to_be_bytes()` as the question indicates, you can try this:

```
Buffer.from(fPlayer.gamesCount.toString(16).padStart(8, '0'), 'hex').reverse()
```